# Asterisk (Digium): how to disable or down span via cli?

Tags: asterisk, dahdi

How to down span via CLI or API?

I found only the one command:

```
CLI> pri destroy span 1
```

but it not suitable for me, because I don’t want to destroy span, but only shutdown specified span.
e.g.:

```
     CLI> pri show spans         
     PRI span 1/0: Up, Active
     PRI span 2/0: Up, Active
     CLI> pri destroy span 1
     PRI span 2/0: Up, Active
```

The required state is:

```
     PRI span 1/0: Down, Active
```

Keep in mind, that the this call is forbidden:

```
     int fd = open("/dev/dahdi/ctl", O_RDWR);
     ioctl(fd, DAHDI_SHUTDOWN, &span);
```

because after that, the call:

```
     ioctl(fd, DAHDI_STARTUP, &span);
```

return unconfigured span.

Answer (score 0):

You have change config and do reload.

Or patch asterisk for needed command.